# Dimension of a topological space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

I want to prove this fact that if X is a topological space which is covered by a family of open subsets {U_i} than dimX=supdimU_i
 One direction I can see that the RHS is less than or equal to the that of LHS...but the other direction is I have not been able to prove..any help is appreciated

Comment: See Keenan's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140066/krull-dimension-of-a-scheme/140078#140078

Comment: @Seth Is it clear that the question is about the topic of Keenan's answer, Krull dimension? Maybe it is covering dimension (tandra should clarify).

Comment: here dim refers to the sup of the length of chain irreducible cloed proper subsets of X which corresponds to the krull dimension of its affine coordinate ring

Comment: So, the topological space you are considering is definitely a scheme then (and in fact an affine scheme?)

Comment: This is an exercise in Hartshorne's book. The question Seth linked to contains a proof.