# Codimension is preserved under base change for given conditions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm working on exercise II.6.1 in Hartshorne and I'm stuck on the following step. I would appreciate some help.

> Let $ X $ be a Noetherian integral scheme. Let $ Z $ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Z}} $ of codimension $1$. Then $X\times Z $ is of codimension $1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_{X}$.

My intuition is to reduce to the affine case by taking an affine open cover of the projective space, but I can't set this up right.

Answer (score 2):

Locally $D$ is given by the vanishing of $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$. Let $Spec\ A$ be an affine open of $X$, so $A$ in a Noetherian integral domain, then $X \times Z$ is locally given by $f \in A[x_0,\ldots, x_n]$, this latter ring which is a Noetherian domain, and hence $f$ is a non-zero divisor and we can apply Krull's Principal Ideal theorem, which says that in a Noetherian ring every minimal prime over $(f)$ has height 1, i.e locally $f$ cuts out a codimension 1 subscheme.
So we can construct an open cover of $X \times P^n_Z$ and $X \times Z$ has codimension 1 subscheme in this each open cover, so it has codimension 1 globally.
For details of this last step, see 
[Krull Dimension of a scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140066/krull-dimension-of-a-scheme)

Comment: One thing to note is that there is some commutative algebra behind the assertion that $Z$ is locally principal.